# Extract parts of a string in R

Tags: regex, r, substring, substr

I have a string of the form

```
stamp = "section_d1_2010-07-01_08_00.txt"
```

and would like to be able to extract parts of this.  I have been able to do this by using repeated str_extract to get to the section I want, e.g. to grab the month

```
month = str_extract(stamp,"2010.+")
month = str_extract(month,"-..")
month = str_extract(month,"..$")
```

however this is terribly inefficient and there has to be a better way.  For this particular example I can use

```
month = substr(stamp,17,18)
```

however am looking for something more versatile (in case the number of digits changes).

I think I need the regular expression to grab what comes AFTER certain flags (the _ or -, or the 3rd _ etc.).  I have tried using sub as well, but had the same problem in that I was needing several to hone into what I actually wanted.

An example of how to get say the month (07 here) and the hour (08 here) would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you expect the input string to always have the same width?

Comment: Have you tried the `gsub` and `str_extract` in my post?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no - the number of characters might change (why I can't just use substr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `strsplit` with regex `[-_]` and `perl=TRUE` option to get all the parts.

```
stamp <- "section_d1_2010-07-01_08_00.txt"
strsplit(stamp, '[-_]')[[1]]
# [1] "section" "d1"      "2010"    "07"      "01"      "08"      "00.txt"
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/8

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
gsub('^.*_\\d+-|-\\d+_.*$', '', stamp)
#[1] "07"
```

For the hour

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(stamp, '(?<=\\d_)\\d+(?=_\\d)')
#[1] "08"
```

Extracting both

```
 str_extract_all(stamp, '(?<=\\d{4}[^0-9])\\d{2}|\\d{2}(?=[^0-9]\\d{2}\\.)')[[1]]
 #[1] "07" "08"
```

Comment: Can the regrex be explained please @akrun :3
I will be looking to extract all numbers that are flanked by letters. In the above example, I am having trouble decoding the regrex that extracts the numbers between the "-" characters.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I tried: `str_extract('(?<=^[[:alpha:]]+)[0-9]+(?=[[:alpha:]]+)', "Glu741ArgfsTer30")`

Comment: Not sure why that is returning `NA`

Comment: str_extract("Glu741ArgfsTer30", '(?<=[A-z]{3})\\d+(?=[A-Z]+)' )
is the answer. I dont know why I have to use `{3}` and not `+`